# Upgrading from 14.04.1 to 14.10

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 14.10

I can't upgrade from 14.04.1 to 14.10 because when I go into software updater, there is no "upgrade button" available.  It just tells me the software is up to date and I click okay to close the window or I can click settings, neither of which help me upgrade.

Anybody got a fix or workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the Update mode.

Your system only looking for "LTS" version, so 14.10 is Normal release. There is settings in Ubuntu where can change this version type and mark it to Normal Release. After that you will get the update notification.

This link will help you - http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/10/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-to-14-10